# Extracting one specific line from parsed JSON string

Tags: json, vba

Trying to pull first value from a parsed JSON string using the JsonConverter library.

What I currently have is:

```
result = objHTTP.responseText

Set parsedResult = JsonConverter.ParseJson(result)

i = 3
For Each Item In parsedResult("From")
    wsSheet0.Cells(i, 12) = parsedResult("From")(Item)("Price")
    i = i + 1
Next

With parsedResult("From")
wsSheet0.Cells(11, 12) = parsedResult("From")("Chocolate")("Price")("AsAtDate")
End With
```

The last line of this gets a `type mismatch` error, so I'm still trying to figure out how to just pull that one line item.

For the sake of clarity, the parsed JSON string looks like:

```
{  
   "From":{  
      "Chocolate":{  
         "Price":1.0,
         "AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"
      },
      "Lime":{  
         "Price":1.35415115,
         "AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"
      },
      "Strawberry":{  
         "Price":1.19517151,
         "AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"
      },
      "Vanilla":{  
         "Price":0.77522986,
         "AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"
      },
      "Blueberry":{  
         "Price":1.00084071,
         "AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"
      },
      "Lemon":{  
         "Price":0.75030012,
         "AsAtDate":"2018-05-04T00:00:00"
      }
   },
   "To":"Chocolate",
   "RequestedDate":"2018-05-22T08:26:16"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
parsedResult("From")("Chocolate")("AsAtDate")
```

Or more generally to get all:

```
parsedResult("From")(item)("AsAtDate")
```